# form:radiobuttons wrong list order

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, radio-button, listitem

Brownser is showing a bad radio buttons order. i dont know why changes showing order.

[I want this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3vZa.png)

[Actually is showing this(WRONG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fR2s.png)

**Code shown in brownser(WRONG):**

```
<input id="sdh.iesdfact1" name="sdh.iesdfact" type="radio" value="3"/>
<label for="sdh.iesdfact1">Con facturas</label>

<input id="sdh.iesdfact2" name="sdh.iesdfact" type="radio" value="2"/>
<label for="sdh.iesdfact2">Facturas requeridas</label>

<input id="sdh.iesdfact3" name="sdh.iesdfact" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked"/>
<label for="sdh.iesdfact3">Sin facturas</label>
```

**Aplication code: Jsp Code:**

```
<label for="sdh.iesdfact”> <spring:message code="sdh.sol.fac"/></label>
        <form:radiobuttons path="sdh.iesdfact" items="${lista_facturas}" />
```

**Aplication code: Java Code:**

```
 public static Map<String,String> cargarFacturas(MessageSource messageSource, Locale locale) {
       Map<String,String> listafacturas = new HashMap<String,String>();
       listafacturas.put("1","Sin facturas”);
       listafacturas.put("2","Facturas requeridas”);
       listafacturas.put("3","Con facturas”);
    return listafacturas;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/alta")
    public String alta(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale)throws Exception{
      AltaForm altaForm = new AltaForm();               
      model.addAttribute("lista_facturas",Utilidades.cargarFacturas(messageSource, locale));
      model.addAttribute("altaForm", altaForm);
      return "alta";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain the order which you added your entries in cargarFacturas method change the Map implementation from HashMap to LinkedHashMap.When you iterate through a Map values HashMap does not retrieve elements in the order in which they were inserted. The values are fetched in a random manner.

Use

```
Map<String,String> listafacturas = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
```

instead of

```
Map<String,String> listafacturas = new HashMap<String,String>();
```